# VBA Word Paste UTF-8 characters from HTML

Tags: html, vba, utf-8, ms-word

This is in follow-up to [Copying HTML to Word via VBA and clipboard loses special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6888606/9873499) (pretty dead)

**Questions:** Is there a method where I can set a `selection` or `range` in Word to a specific encoding so that I can obtain UTF-8 characters on paste? Or better: Can I control the coding on paste?

*Issues:*

1. Both [`selection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/selection-object-word) and [`range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-object-word) don't have a method to set an encoding within it on the docs. The closest is to [toggle the coding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/selection-togglecharactercode-method-word) (but it doesn't do anything). Same goes to [Paste](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-paste-method-word) and [PasteSpecial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-word) - don't really have documentation much in them.
2. I can't go with a solution to create a temporary file so that I can save it as an html file and insert the text into the `range` - admin issues

Original text (in html):
`Alle Füchse <b>sprangen</b> über den <em>großen</em> Bären.`

Expected text (formatted in Word):
`Alle Füchse`**`sprangen`**`über den`*`großen`*`Bären.`

Current text (with the code*):
`Alle Fchse`**`sprangen`**`ber den`*`groߥn`*`B䲥n.`

*  As in the follow-up link and using pasting in the range instead of the [`GetHTMLClipboard`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/274326/how-to-add-html-code-to-the-clipboard-by-using-visual-basic)(which actually gets the encoding right, but leaves the html format tags in instead of formatting).

Comment: No, the Word object model has nothing like this. You'd need to do some kind of conversion on the content before pasting into Word. You might try substituting the entity references: `&szlig;` and `&uuml;`. The other possibilty would be to convert to valid Word Open XML (flat OPC format), then you could use the `InsertXML` method.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that! I think the first resolution is kind of simpler  **but works** (even if as a work-around).